# Divs order in mobile layout - Bootstrap 4 Rows and Columns

Tags: html, css, flexbox, bootstrap-4, responsive

I am trying to make a layout work, using Bootstrap 4, but there is a problem with the positioning of elements on mobile. Maybe someone here could help me out, please :)

Here is the layout I want:

[Image with layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kn63s.jpg)

So, as you can see it's a 2-column layout for desktop and 1-column layout for mobile.

To create this layout I created a row and made 2 columns:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-8 col-12">
        <div id="productimage"></div>
        <div id="description"></div>
        <div id="reviews"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-4 col-12">
        <div id="pricebook"></div>
        <div id="location"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So, on desktop this works smoothly.

But on mobile, I want Price & Book div from Column 2, to actually go right below the Product Image div. However, it obviously goes below Reviews div with the current code.

So, how could I make this work?

Thanks!

(I've tried making all divs to be columns, but then the desktop layout breaks if the height of the elements is not ideal, and that happens, because the divs in the right column on desktop can have different height depending on content. I've tried separating this into more rows, but same problem).

Comment: I believe you can find the answer you're looking for in the bootstrap documentation. Check out this link and go to the section "Order classes."
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/#order-classes

Answer (score 0):

You could also try creating a duplicate "Price & Book" div which remains hidden in desktop view and only shows up in mobile view. Where as the original "Price & Book" div should only be visible in desktop view.

[Responsive utilities in Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/css/#responsive-utilities-classes)